# Confusion of contentView, scrollView, frame and bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

This has been a problem with understanding how these things fit together.  Can someone explain once and for all what is the difference and how they are used together?

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific regarding what you don't understand. The "once and for all" is the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A scroll view manages a content view, which is usually larger than the scroll view itself. The scroll view is like a window that shows just a piece of the larger content view. As you scroll, the content view moves so that different parts of it appear in the window.

Every view as `frame` and `bounds` properties. The `frame` of a view is the rectangle that encloses the view in the coordinate system of its superview. The `bounds` is the same rectangle, but expressed in the view's own coordinate system.

Comment: This is the exact answer to my inexact question.

Answer (score 3):

Start here: [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503).

Comment: Your answer is 2nd only to "Google is your best friend".

Comment: First of all, your question doesn't really belong here. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). Second, I really think you should read the guide for `UIView` **before** you start working with it.

Comment: I can't upvote this because it's not itself a particularly good SO answer, but it is the only correct answer to such an unspecific question.

Comment: Is ok, some one was nice enough to give it a shot.

Comment: +1 It may not answer the question directly, but I think that pointing someone to documentation that provides the answer is useful. One does have to wonder why the OP asked here instead of doing some basic research. The difference between [frame](http://bit.ly/TW2Tk0) and [bounds](http://bit.ly/OwdnFB), for example, is explained on the [UIView class reference page](http://bit.ly/GGjAFB) almost exactly the way I explained it above.